# Conservative two-dimensional vector fields - contradiction between theorems?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble understanding the subject of two-dimensional vector fields:

**Definition** : A two dimensional vector field $(P,Q)$ which is defined in $D\subseteq \mathbb{R} ^2 $ if there exists a function $F\in C^1 (D)$ for which $\nabla F= (P,Q)$ .

**Theorem**: Let (P,Q) be a vector field with components that have continuous first order partial derivatives :
F is conservative if and only if  $\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r} $ for all closed curves C.

and in addition

**Theorem:** In a simply-connected domain D, if $(P,Q) \in C^1 (D) $ and $P_y=Q_x $ then $(P,Q)$ is a conservative field in $D$ .

Now for my question:

Given the famous vector field $\left( -\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2 }, \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2 } \right) $ , we obviously have $ P_y = Q_x =\frac{y^2 -x^2 }{x^2 + y^2 }$ and that $(P,Q)\in C^1 (D) $ in every domain $D$ not containing $(0,0)$. 
So, I expect $(P,Q)$ to be a conservative vector field in every simply-connected domain $D$, not containing the origin (for example, let $D$ be a circle of radius 1 around $(0,2)$ ) ! But, a direct computation yields that the only possible potential for this field is: $ arctan(\frac{y}{x}) $ which is not even defined (and obviously not continuously differentiable) on the $y$-axis! So, by the definition, our vector field is not conservative (the scalar potential function must be $C^1 (D)$ ) .

Where is my mistake ? 
Will someone please help me ? I am becoming more and more desperate with this

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It is defined on the $x$-axis. It isn't defined on the $y$-axis, which is when $x=0$.

Comment: you are right. I have edited the first message . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a sample of what happens, the function

$$g(x,y):=\begin{cases}\arctan\left(y\over x\right) &\text{if } x>0\\
{\pi\over 2}-\arctan\left({x\over y}\right)&\text{if }y>0\wedge x\le 0\\
-\frac\pi2-\arctan\left({x\over y}\right)&\text{if }y<0\wedge x\le 0\end{cases}$$

Is in $C^\infty(\Omega)$, where $\Omega:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: y\neq 0\vee x>0\}$

$\Omega$ is indeed a simply connected subset of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ which is maximal by inclusion "$\subseteq$".

And you can see by straight-forward calculation that $\nabla g$ is your vector field.

**Added (1)**

Of course, it cannot be extended to a continuous function on the whole plane, or even on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, because for instance $$\begin{cases}\lim_{y\to 0^+} g(-1,y)=\pi\\\lim_{y\to 0^-}g(-1,y)=-\pi\end{cases}$$

**Added (2)**

In the general case of a closed form, as long as your domain has trivial homotopy you are guaranteed to be able to coherently and differentiably paste local protentials, roughly as I did above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. Just to make sure I understand - your potential (with a slight addition of the case $x<0, y=0$ ) shows that indeed, there exists a potential in every simply connected domain (which does not contain the origin) ? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was a bit rude, @CrazyStatistician. I'll add a precisation in the answer, so that I have space to write it better.

Comment: Great. I think I got it.  Thanks a lot !